# How to embeded Datetime into SQL String

Tags: java, sql, datetime

I have a need to use `Statement.executeUpdate()` to insert data into Database.
So every parameter must be embeded into a SQL string.
In Database, the type of two columns are datetime: Date1 and Date2
At client side, if I use following statement:

```
String SQLString = "INSERT INTO Position (" +
    ......
    "Date1, " +
    ......
    "Date2) " +
    "VALUES(" +
    ......
    //"2012-05-29 16:28:58.555" + ", " + // runtime error, always say error at 16
    //"2012-05-29" + ", " + // no runtime error, but lost time and result date is also not correct
    //"10-06-02" + ", " + // no runtime error, but it adds 2 days beginning at 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
    ......
    null
    ")";
```

Can anyone tell me how to correctly embedded Datetime into SQL String?

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226390/sql-insert-system-date-into-table

Answer (score 4):

You should use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and pass the date field ad [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) ...

```
String SQLString = "INSERT INTO Position (Date1) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(SQLString);
prest.setDate(1,new Date());
prest.executeUpdate()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I HAVE TO use Statement.executeUpdate(), so Can anyone tell me how to correctly embedded Datetime into SQL String?

Comment: What is the SQL version ? Should work with : YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss or without the time simply with : YYYY-MM-dd or YYYYMMdd

Answer (score 2):

First up, you have to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Then you could do something like:

```
statement.setDate(2, new Date());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I HAVE TO use Statement.executeUpdate(), so Can anyone tell me how to correctly embedded Datetime into SQL String?