# JDBC statement is not executed (No errors)

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working on a little Minecraft Plugin. I'm trying to insert data into the database with my `DatabaseManager` class but for some reason its not working. There are no error messages and the password and user name are correct. Also I've tried to insert the sql code manually into the database and it works, so there are no sql syntax errors. For me it seems like the statement is not executed for some reason but I cant find the failure. Below is the code of my class.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseManager {
  Connection conn = null; 
  Statement stmt  = null ;
  ResultSet result = null;

  String user = "root" ;
  String pass = "";

  public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException{
      try{
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metrocraft",user,pass);
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

      }catch (Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
         if(result != null)
             result.close();
         if(stmt != null)
             stmt.close();
         if(conn != null)
             conn.close();
      }
      return result ;
  }
  //Metrocraft relevant code 

  public void addZone(double p1X , double p1Y,double p2X,double p2Y) throws SQLException{
      String sql = "INSERT INTO `zones`( `p1X`, `p1Y`,`p2X`, `p2Y`) VALUES (" + p1X + ","+ p1Y+","+p2X+","+p2Y+"); ";
      System.out.print(sql);
      executeQuery(sql);
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3226433/1008671).

Comment: Your might want to reconsider opening and closing your database connection each time you need to run a query. Opening is very expensive (time consuming), and will cause your mod to be slow whenever it needs to query. Instead, I'd suggest opening your connection when you first need to query (or when your mod starts up), keep it open, and then close it when your mod shuts down. This way you re-use the connection multiple times, and save the costs of reopening continuously.

Comment: Yeah thank you ill think about this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're risking a malicious attack though [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Switch to prepared statements. BTW, use `executeUpdate` for database write operations

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
result = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I would also mention why you use `PreparedStatement` opposed to `stmt = conn.createStatement(); stmt.executeQuery(query);`

Answer (score 0):

You have not loaded the drive in your program before establishing the database connection.so load the drive using the following command

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

You have to update your try catch block as mention below

```
try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metrocraft",user,pass);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Just a note - manually loading the driver via `Class.forName()` is not longer needed with JDBC 4.0 and above. So if you recently downloaded the JDBC driver, you do not need to load it manually.